# Some mp3's won't play in html5 audio player

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am using the jplayer html5 media player on the web site i am developing, but it won't play some mp3's on Chrome. I've tried to play those mp3's in the browser's native player and it wont play neither. From the other side when i download them to the local drive and when i drag them to the browser's window they are playing normally.

Here is the link for the page with  [audio files](http://www.pioneer.org.uk/allaudio.php) .

Link for the [song that won't play](http://www.pioneer.org.uk/media/audios/Main%20Session%202%20-%20Mark%20Stibbe%20-%20Fathers.mp3)

This file plays fine -> Andy Flannigan:Decisions Are Made By Those Who Show Up

Any ideas? Please advise...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I discovered that some MP3 files were Layer 2 instead of Layer 3.
You can use [Checkmate MP3 Checker](http://checkmate.gissen.nl/) (tiny and freeware) to check the Layer version of your files.

You can convert your files to Layer 3 using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and the answer turned out to be the bit rate of the mp3 file. The audio tag is quite sensitive about this. Anything above 128mbps it will not play. A lot of encoders automatically choose the highest quality bit rate (usually around 320mbps) and the audio tag won't play them. Check them (audio properties will tell you fairly easily) and re-upload them. Strangely, OGG doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem, but better safe than sorry. HTH.

OK, i just downloaded the "file that won't play", and found the Sample rate at 16000hz (should be 44100hz), and the bit rate 32-bit(float), which should be 16-bit (PCM). Resample, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the size of the MP3. I'm having a similar issue w/ jPlayer - small MP3's play fine, large ones don't fully load before the request gets cancelled.